# Ubuntu 14.04 can't get other's presence/status to show up in empathy 3.8.6

Tags: empathy

The title says it all:  in the contacts window, all the information boxes etc.  say that everyone is offline, which I happen to know is not true because one of my friends started a chat with me while simultaneously appearing to be offline.  I got him to change his state/presence setting a few times.  empathy-debugger saw a bunch of stuff which looked like plausible protocol, and the correct information is displayed by thunderbird.  I don't seem to be able to initiate any chats, either.

Does any of this sound familiar?  This behaviour seems so broken that I feel I must be doing something wrong, but I have no idea what.